# What value has Visual Studios CSS support?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

So I'm supposed to be a .Net Developer but have found myself getting stuck with allot of css and html stuff lately. I would now consider myself to be very strong in css and all it's intricacies. With that said I still see any use it any of the Visual Studio support for it outside of the intellisense (when it works).

I want to ask if anyone developers that view themselves strong in css are using any of the Visual Studio 2008 css support features and if so what they are and why they use them over say firebug?

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hand coded all the way for me.

Firebug is really good for getting to the bottom of wierd browser issues, but generally I have IE, Chrome and Firefox open when I'm coding html & CSS, and I just make sure I hit the refresh button often enough in all three of them to make sure I don't get any nasty suprises after writing a pile of css.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I turn off all of the Visual Studio CSS stuff.  It's not exactly well made.  Instead I've been using MS Expression to build master pages and manage CSS files.  It is light years ahead of VS.

That said, I see firebug as a complimentary product, not really a replacement.  I use FireBug and the equivalents in safari, chrome, and IE 8 to see what's going on with the internals of a particular element on a page.  I use Expression to edit and maintain the css.